# Algorithm for searching withing a group of words

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, search

I have a group of words in the below format :

a1 , a2, a3 , a4

b1 , b2 , b3 , b4 , b5 ..

c1 , c2 ...

.

.

.

and so on .

Test case :

User input : a3

Out put : a1 , a2,a3,a4

User input : b1

Output : b1,b2,b3,b4,b5

Total rows : 40000
In each row there could be 1-100 combinations .

What could be be the most effective way of getting the output

Thanks

Comment: `grep` would probably be most effective.

Comment: Can explain more about two things? 1 - each row in the input 2 - the relation of b1 nad b1,b2,b3...

Comment: I mean are the rows just like x1 x2 x3 x? ... and in the test case is the input something like x1? what are the valid inputs?

Comment: the inputs could be like :Row 1 : activation|activated|activator|activating

Comment: Row 2 : actualization|actualized

Comment: so each row is guaranteed to have a fixed length prefix ?

Comment: how about an array of arraylists, where the main array contains column 1 and a reference to an arraylist. For example data[2] will have `c1` and an arraylist containing `c1,c2,c3..`

Comment: each row could be 1-100 combinations mean maximum input is 40,000 rows, each of 100 words?

Comment: Sorry I miss one point too: can different rows contain same words?

Comment: So you just want to output the line that contains the word that the user entered?

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on n.m.'s answer (which seems spot on),

use grep, ex.,

```
grep 'activation' filename
```

This may help:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/